# Update Preview Button - StorageException occurred while persisting PublicationMapping

Tags: content-delivery, 2013, session-preview

I keep running into this issue where when I click the "Update Preview" button it throws the follow error in the logs.  Everything seems fine up until the the request is made to post the content to the DB.  In the event log there is an error that says

> Unable to update the changes using OData Service. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService Errorcode: 1003

Under closer examination with Fiddler, I can see the request being sent properly but the response is a 500 error.  Even though the message returned is says its a 400 error.

The following is the error in the cd_core log.  I'm not sure why its trying to map insert to PUBLICATION_MAPPINGS since that table isn't in the DB.

> 2013-07-10 23:57:01,151 ERROR PublicationMappingUtils - StorageException occurred while persisting PublicationMapping!
>   com.tridion.broker.StorageException: Rollback took place, didn't persist., org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Invalid object name 'PUBLICATION_MAPPINGS'., org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Invalid object name 'PUBLICATION_MAPPINGS'.
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPABaseDAO.create(JPABaseDAO.java:105) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPAPublicationMappingDAO.store(JPAPublicationMappingDAO.java:42) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.wrapper.utils.PublicationMappingUtils.reserveNewVirtualPublicationId(PublicationMappingUtils.java:45) ~[cd_wrapper.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.wrapper.utils.MethodHandlerUtils.injectVirtualPublicationId(MethodHandlerUtils.java:168) [cd_wrapper.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.wrapper.utils.MethodHandlerUtils.injectVirtualPublicationId(MethodHandlerUtils.java:133) [cd_wrapper.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.methodhandlers.WriteMethodHandler.rewriteWriteOperationArgument(WriteMethodHandler.java:115) [cd_session.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.methodhandlers.WriteMethodHandler.rewriteWriteOperationArguments(WriteMethodHandler.java:88) [cd_session.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.methodhandlers.WriteMethodHandler.invokeMethod(WriteMethodHandler.java:37) [cd_session.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.persistence.session.methodhandlers.SessionProxyMethodHandler.invoke(SessionProxyMethodHandler.java:87) [cd_session.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.storage.dao.ItemDAO_$$_javassist_33.store(ItemDAO_$$_javassist_33.java) [cd_datalayer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.WritableItemMetasEntryService.store(WritableItemMetasEntryService.java:105) [cd_preview_webservice.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.WritableItemMetasEntryService.update(WritableItemMetasEntryService.java:85) [cd_preview_webservice.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.WritableItemMetasEntryService.update(WritableItemMetasEntryService.java:26) [cd_preview_webservice.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.AbstractWritableEntryService.update(AbstractWritableEntryService.java:72) [cd_preview_webservice.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.WritablePageMetasEntryService.update(WritablePageMetasEntryService.java:27) [cd_preview_webservice.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.updateODataEntity(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:418) [cd_odata.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchHandler.handleChangeSet(ODataBatchHandler.java:127) [cd_odata.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchHandler.handleBatch(ODataBatchHandler.java:51) [cd_odata.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataWebserviceHandler.handleBatch(ODataWebserviceHandler.java:386) [cd_odata.jar:na]
>   2013-07-10 23:57:01,151 ERROR ODataBatchHandler - Some serious error happened at runtime!
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 2013 Broker database there should be a table PUBLICATION_MAPPINGS, so maybe you don't have the correct Broker database? Check the TDS_DB_INFO table, that should have one record with the following data:

<kbd>DB_VERSION</kbd><kbd>DESCRIPTION</kbd>                   <kbd>INSTALLATION_TYPE</kbd>                                         
<kbd>7.0.0.0</kbd>           <kbd>Content Broker Database</kbd><kbd>SDL Tridion 2013 Database Manager Installation</kbd>

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.  The Broker was updated but the Session Preview DB wasn't.